# Document Comparison Engine/Search

Tags: php, comparison, document

I have a large amount of document files that include .pdf, .one, .doc, .docx, etc.  I am trying to find a way to compare the text contents of the files to look for duplicates or near matches.  I have a site build on a LAMP stack that users upload the files to.  I could either compare the documents on upload or run a cron job.  I have seen Apache Lucene mentioned in similar context, and Zend Search Lucene seems to be a powerful PHP version of it, but they are more search-oriented than comparison.  Would there be a way to leverage these for a comparison purpose?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I think comparing files for matches would likely be tons easier than comparing for near matches. It would likely take a combo of approaches.

Right off the bat, I would use something like [hash_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-file.php)() to get hash values for your file contents. You can then have a super short representation of the contents of your file which you can use to match up with other file hashes to look for duplicates. You may try hashing different values or trying to gather up some information about your files such as [strlen](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php)() or something like that for comparisons of "near duplicate". Hopefully this is helpful. Sounds like a challenge for sure.

Comment: Truthfully, near matches are what I need to find.  I need to be able to find if there is a file in, for example, a .doc format that has the same content(text) as a .one file.